# Convert list of words in Text file to Word Vectors

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I have a text file with million of rows which I wanted to convert into word vectors and later on I can compare these vectors with a search keyword and see which all texts are closer to the search keyword.

My Dilemma is all the training files that I have seen for the Word2vec are in the form of paragraphs so that each word has some contextual meaning within that file. Now my file here is independent and contains different keywords in each row.

My question is whether is it possible to create word embedding using this text file or not, if not then what's the best approach for searching a matching search keyword in this million of texts

**My File Structure: **

```
Walmart
Home Depot
Home Depot
Sears
Walmart
Sams Club
GreenMile
Walgreen
```

**Expected**

```
search Text : 'WAL'
```

**Result from My File:**

```
WALGREEN
WALMART
WALMART
```

Comment: The issue as I see it, as you stated, is that you lack any sort of context. In the sample data you posted, what would a relationship between the values look like? What would be a possible output for a given input? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @G.Anderson Not sure why downvote, any ways I've updated the Question for the exact answer but I was more interested to solve this using word2vec approach and hence the question was whether these kind of files can be trained using word2vec approach or not

Comment: Why would the query `WAL` not return `Walgreens`?

Comment: This looks more like [autocomplete](https://pypi.org/project/autocomplete/) than any sort of word vectorization. To your question, the downvote was due to lack of example, as I commented. You provided, so I removed the downvote.

Comment: OK, this is definitely an XY problem - you are trying to do a text-based search. You don't need word vectors, they won't help you with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

### Embeddings

Lets step back and understand what is word2vec. Word2vec (like Glove, FastText etc) is a way to represent words as vectors. ML models don't understand words they only understand numbers so when we are dealing with words we would want to convert them into numbers (vectors). One-hot encoding is one naive way of encoding words as vectors. But for a large vocabulary one-hot encoding become too long. Also there is no semantic relationship between one-hot encoded word.

With DL came the distributed representation of words (called word embeddings). One important property of these word embeddings is that the vector distance between related words is small compared to the distance between unrelated words. i.e `distance(apple,orange) < distance(apple,cat)`

So how are these embedding model trained ? The embedding models are trained on (very) huge corpus of text. When you have huge corpus of text the model will learn that the apple are orange are used (many times) in same context. It will learn that the apple and orange are related. So to train a good embedding model you need huge corpus of text (not independent words because independent words have no context).

However, one rarely trains a word embedding model form scratch because good embedding model are available in open source. However, if your text is domain specific (say medical) then you do a transfer learning on openly available word embeddings.

#### Out of vocabulary (OOV) words

Word embedding like word2vec and Glove cannot return an embedding for OOV words. However the embeddings like FastText (thanks to @gojom for pointing it out) handle OOV words by breaking them into n-grams of chars and build a vector by summing up subword vectors that would make up the word.

### Problem

Coming to your problem,

**Case 1:** lets say the user enters a word `WAL`, first of all it is not a valid English word so it will not be in vocabulary and it is hard to mind a meaning full vector to it. Embeddings like FastText handling them by breaking it into n-grams. This approach gives good embeddings for misspelled words or slang.

**Case 2:** Lets say the user enters a word `WALL` and if you plan to use vector similarly to find closest word it will never be close to `Walmart` because semantically they are not related. It will rather be close to words like `window, paint, door`.

### Conclusion

If your search is for semantically similar words, then solution using vector embeddings will be good. On the other hand, if your search is based on lexicons then vectors embeddings will be of no help.

Comment: This is a good overview of vectorization, +1 from me. It might also be worth noting _how_ vectors are learned from scratch, using single words, n-grams in both directions, and surrounding context. All of which is missing in this example.

Comment: Note FastText (& some other similar methods) could find candidates from a fragment like `wal`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to find `walmart` from a fragment like `wal`, you'd more likely use something like:

- a substring or prefix search through all entries; or
- a reverse-index-of-character-n-grams; or
- some sort of edit-distance calculated against all entries or a subset of likely candidates

That is, from your example desired output, this is not really a job for word-vectors, even though some algorithms, like FastText, will be able to provide rough vectors for word-fragments based on their overlap with trained words.

If in fact you want to find *similar* stores, word-vectors might theoretically be useful. But the problem given your example input is that such word-vector algorithms require examples of tokens used *in context*, from sequences-of-tokens that co-appear in natural-language-like relationships. And you want lots of data featuring varied examples-in-context, to capture subtle gradations of mutual relationships.

While your existing single-column of short entity-names (stores) can't provide that, maybe you have something applicable elsewhere, if you have richer data sources. Some ideas might be:

- lists of stores visited by a single customer
- lists of stores carrying the same product/UPC
- text from a much larger corpus (such as web-crawled text, or maybe Wikipedia) in which there are sufficient in-context usages of each store-name. (You'd just throw out all the other words created from such training - but the vectors for your tokens-of-interest might still be of use in your domain.)